# onClick event that will save the clicked Anchor's name using PHP-Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a 4 links, and each time I click one of them it will auto increment the value of the priority number here's the code for that

```html
<div id ="qnum" style = "text-align: center; font-size: 5em; margin-top: 0px"></div>
<div class = "container" style = "text-align: center; margin-top: 100px;">
<form id="getTicketForm" name="getTicketForm" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="hiddenqnum" id="hiddenqnum" value="">
    <a href="#" onClick="getPnumber()" style = "font-size: 3em;" name = "transaction" value = "payment" id = "payment">Payment</a><br />
    <a href="#" onClick="getPnumber()" style = "font-size: 3em;" name = "transaction" value = "landtax" id = "landtax">Land Tax</a><br />
    <a href="#" onClick="getPnumber()" style = "font-size: 3em;" name = "transaction" value = "spl" id = "spl">Special Lane</a><br />
    <a href="#" onClick="getPnumber()" style = "font-size: 3em;" name = "transaction" value = "bpld" id = "bpld">BPLD</a><br />
    </form>
</div>
```

and this is the function getPnumber()

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
//display Priority Number
    var num = 1;
    var queue = ('0000'+num).slice(-4);;
    document.getElementById("qnum").innerHTML = "Your Priority Number is" +  "<br>" + queue;
//if button is clicked, queue will increment
    function getPnumber() {
        num += 1;
        var queue = ('0000'+num).slice(-4);;
        document.getElementById("qnum").innerHTML = "Your Priority Number is" + "<br>" + queue;

        
        document.getTicketForm.hiddenqnum.value = queue;
       
    };

</script>
```

i have no problem in that part, but i want also to save the link's value & priority number into database
here's my script,

```js
function save(){

$(document.ready)(function(){
    $('#getTicketForm').click(function(){
        var qnumber = $("input[name=hiddenqnum]").val();
        var transaction = $().val();
     
            $.ajax({
                url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/queue',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    qnumber : qnumber,
                    transaction : transaction
                },
                success : function(data){
                    console log.(data);
                }
            })
    });
});
};

</script>
```

and later i will change my link's onclick into  function Onclick()
which is

```js
<script>
function onClick(){
 getPnumber();
 save();
};
</script>
```

i hope you could help me in saving the links value and priority while it still auto increments after clicking.
by the way i am using php-codeigniter
anyway my issue is my function save() i can't save to my DB, i also have a problem in getting the priority number from hidden text and pass it to var qnumber

Comment: what is your issue atm?

Comment: oh i'm sorry. anyway my issue is my function save() i can't save to my DB, i also have a problem in getting the priority number from hidden text and pass it to var qnumber.

Comment: How and what you need get using var transaction = $().val(); ???

Comment: I had added my answer. let me if it's work for you...

Comment: hello @DanielSmith it works well, thankyou very much for the help. tho i wanted to make the links the direct button for saving and printing receipt at the same time.but you gave me the best code for my project. i'll use it and modify the rest that i needed.

Comment: I did not get your print issue. Seems you need to create a new post for it. Please mark my answer as accepted for this if it worked for you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using jQuery as well. Also, you need to add one more input field to track `transaction` value also. I had added a new Button as well for your Ajax calling.

Here you go -

```
<div id="qnum" style="padding:10px 20px;background:yellow;height:50px;color:#000;"></div>
<div class="container" style="padding:10px 20px;text-align:left;border:1px solid #ddd">
  <form id="getTicketForm" name="getTicketForm" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="hiddenqnum" id="hiddenqnum" value="" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="hiddentransaction" id="hiddentransaction" value="" /><br />
    <a href="#" name="transaction" value="payment" id="payment">Payment</a><br />
    <a href="#" name="transaction" value = "landtax" id="landtax">Land Tax</a><br />
    <a href="#" name="transaction" value = "spl" id="spl">Special Lane</a><br />
    <a href="#" name="transaction" value = "bpld" id="bpld">BPLD</a><br />
    <button type="button" id="savetodb">Save to db</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var num = 1;

$(document).ready(function(){
  var queue = ('0000'+num).slice(-4);
  $("#qnum").html("Your Priority Number is :"+ queue);

  $("a[name=transaction]").each(function() {
    $(this).on("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      getPnumber($(this).attr('id'));
    });
  });

  $('#savetodb').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var qnumber = $("input[name='hiddenqnum']").val();
    var transaction = $("input[name=hiddentransaction]").val();

    $.ajax({
      // Do your ajax call using qnumber, transaction value here
    });

  });

});

function getPnumber(transaction) {
  num += 1;
  var queue = ('0000'+num).slice(-4);;
  $("#qnum").html("Your Priority Number is :"+ queue);
  $("input[name='hiddenqnum']").val(queue);
  $("input[name='hiddentransaction']").val(transaction);
};
```